# How to dynamically register the bean specific properties on bean initialization

Tags: spring, properties, spring-boot, placeholder, consul

I want to register the bean specific properties on bean creation if not exists in the application. For example

```
public class BeanOne {
    @Value("${prop1}")
    private String property1;
}

public class BeanTwo {
    @Value("${prop2}")
    private String property2;
}
```

I want to register the property 'prop1' and 'prop2' to instantiate the above two beans successfully.

My application is configured with spring-cloud-consul-config. By default consul is not configured with these properties in that time, application will automatically register these properties into consul through ecwid/consul-api

Currently the application throws "IllegalArgumentException" with message "Could not resolve placeholder 'prop1' in string value "${prop1}"

Any Suggestions to avoid the above error.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can do this.

My preferred approach is to set the properties in one or more files externally and then use the @PropertySource("file:///full-path-to-property-file") annotation in a @Configuration class.

This approach, combined with Spring Profiles is very powerful.

Example if you are not using profiles:

1. Create an application.properties file somewhere on your PC. A good
   place to put this is ${user.home}/.somefolder/application.properties
2. Add the values for prop1 and prop2
3. Change the permissions on that folder and file. For example you can
   run chmod u on .somefolder and chmod 600 on the properties file
4. Create a Spring Java Configuration class and annotate it with
   @Configuration. For example you can create an ApplicationConfig
   class in a sub package of your Spring Boot application and annotate
   it with @Configuration
5. Add the @PropertySource annotations as follows:
   @PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/.somefolder/application.properties")

An example from my [course](http://academy.devopsfolks.com) on Spring Boot, AWS, Bootstrap and Stripe:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.devopsbuddy.backend.persistence.repositories")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.devopsbuddy.backend.persistence.domain.backend")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/.devopsbuddy/application-common.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {
}
```

That's it!